# deploying flask app to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask

I installed flask on my AWS EC2 machine.

now, from a local machine, the website is supposed to load with localhost and port 5000  but it is not working similarly with http::5000

I tried to add a rule in Security groups as :  All TCP, 0.0.0.0/0  -- I am not sure how to allow in-bound traffic to this box.

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: [link1](http://exploreflask.com/deployment.html)                   [link2](http://skien.cc/blog/2013/01/07/using-flask-with-nginx-and-uwsgi/) explore these links..you will do it eventually.

Comment: when you say localhost is that what your flask app in bound too? You may want to 0.0.0.0

Comment: when you add rules to your security group you can add them in outbound and in inbound. try adding an inbound rule to http on port 5000 accessible from all IPs.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with this.  Until I tried adding an inbound custom tcp rule to my security group associated with the running instance.

Something like:

```
Custom TCP Rule, Protocol: TCP, Port Range: 5000, Source: 0.0.0.0/0

Custom TCP Rule, Protocol: TCP, Port Range: 5000, Source: ::/0
```